# TikZ sharp vs flat angles

Tags: tikz-pgf

With `\draw (??,??)--(??,??)--(??,??)` syntax TikZ sometimes makes "sharp" joint, while sometimes leaves the joint "flat" - see the picture. It seems that the treshold angle is about arctan(0.2)=11.3 degree (for larger angles joint will be sharp). Can one force TikZ to draw sharp joints for very small angles and flat joints for large angles?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (.2,0)--(0,0)--(.2,0.04);
\node[font=\tiny] at (.8,0) {flat joint};

\scope[shift={(0,-.5)}]
\draw (.2,0)--(0,0)--(.2,0.041);
\node[font=\tiny] at (.8,0) {sharp joint};
\endscope



\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Half duplicate of [Adjust a path with TikZ - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430108/adjust-a-path-with-tikz)

Comment: // the one you called "sharp" and "flat" is "miter" and "bevel" in TikZ respectively. The one linked above covers how to convert miter to bevel, but not vice versa; but if you know what it's called it's trivial to fix

Comment: I think that the issue posted here is not fixable, since even in `miter` (default), the angle is not sharp. Maybe a small bug.

Comment: @SebGlav: doesn't the `miter limit` control this behavior?

Comment: @jak123 Yes, you're right, I forgot about this command ;) I thought it was only to limit the miter, not to expand it. It works fine using `\draw[miter limit=30] (.2,0)--(0,0)--(.2,0.04);`. Make it an answer, it will be upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can control this by the `miter limit` option:

```
\draw[miter limit=20] (.2,0)--(0,0)--(.2,0.04);
```

At sharp angles, joints might extend beyond the line thickness limit. The limit of how far extension is allowed is controlled by the `miter limit` option. The default `miter limit` in TikZ is 10.

The miter limit is [calculated as](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-miterlimit):

```
         1
------------------.
  sin(angle / 2)
```

In your examples, the first line `(0,0) - (0.2, 0) - (0.2, 0.04)` makes an angle of 11.31 deg, which has a miter factor of 10.15, which is above the default limit.

In the second example, `(0,0) - (0.2, 0) - (0.2, 0.041)`, the angle is 11.56 deg and the miter factor is 9.91, which is below the default limit.

As per @Paul Gabroit comment, here is a snapshot from [PDF 32000-1:2008](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/PDF32000_2008.pdf) (p. 126):

[image: PDF 32000-1:2008]

Comment: Excellent and comprehensive answer! +1

Comment: Extract from "PDF 32000-1:2008": _`miter limit` (number) The maximum length of mitered line joins for stroked paths. This parameter limits the length of “spikes” produced when line segments join at sharp angles. Initial value: 10.0, for a miter cutoff below approximately 11.5 degrees._